# C# Winform event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I have 2 constructors in my class:

```
public partial class Fiche_Ordre : Le_MainForm
    {
         public Fiche_Ordre()
              {
                  InitializeComponent();           
                  Constuct_Page();            
              }

              public Fiche_Ordre(string OrderID): this()
              {


                    Pers_Ordre oPersOrdr = oOrder_BL.Get_OrdreOne_BL(ClientID, Convert.ToInt32(OrderID), false);

                textEdit_RefExpred.Text = oPersOrdr.RefExpd;
                lookUpEdit_Agence.EditValue = oPersOrdr.Agence;
                lookUpEdit_Transport.EditValue = oPersOrdr.Transporteur;

                lookUpEdit_Dest.EditValue = oPersOrdr.DestId;
    ..................

              }


              public void Constuct_Page()
              {
                  try
                  {
                      ClientID = Program.Le_ClientID;
                      ....

              #region LookUpEdidt Destinataire

                   lookUpEdit_Dest.Properties.DataSource = Auxiliaire_BL.FillCombo_BL(false, ClientID).Tables["ComboFill"];
                   lookUpEdit_Dest.Properties.ValueMember = "CODE_DEST";
                   lookUpEdit_Dest.Properties.DisplayMember = "CODE_DEST";
                   LookUpColumnInfoCollection coll_Dest = lookUpEdit_Dest.Properties.Columns;
                   // A column to display the ProductID field's values.
                   coll_Dest.Add(new LookUpColumnInfo("CODE_DEST", 0, "Code Destinataire"));
                   // A column to display the ProductName field's values.
                   coll_Dest.Add(new LookUpColumnInfo("RS_NOM", 0, "Raison Social"));
                   //  Set column widths according to their contents and resize the popup, if required.   
                   lookUpEdit_Dest.Properties.BestFitMode = BestFitMode.BestFitResizePopup;
                   // Enable auto completion search mode.
                   lookUpEdit_Dest.Properties.SearchMode = SearchMode.AutoComplete;
                   // Specify the column against which to perform the search.
                   lookUpEdit_Dest.Properties.AutoSearchColumnIndex = 1;
                   lookUpEdit_Dest.EditValueChanged += new EventHandler(lookUpEdit_Dest_EditValueChanged);
              #endregion
        ...
        }
```

It is strange, because when I use `public Fiche_Ordre()` it does not fire `new EventHandler(lookUpEdit_Dest_EditValueChanged);`; but when I use `public Fiche_Ordre(string OrderID)`, it does fire the event handler.

Is this normal or not?

the first constuctor it call from Main form

```
 public partial class Le_MainForm : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
    {
        public Le_MainForm()
        { 
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Name = "MainUSER";

            if (Program.IsFA) barButtonItem_OrdList.Visibility = DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItemVisibility.Never;


        }

 private void barButtonItem_CreatOrdreAller_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Close_AllForm();
            Program.AllerRetour = "Ordre Aller";
            Fiche_Ordre f_Fiche = new Fiche_Ordre();

            f_Fiche.Show();
        }
```

and the second constructor i call it from

```
public partial class Liste_Ordres : Le_MainForm
    {

     private void Liste_DobleClic(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    Program.OrderId = gridView_Liste_Ordres.GetFocusedRowCellValue("NO_ORDRE").ToString();
                    this.Hide();
                    Fiche_Ordre f_Fiche = new Fiche_Ordre(gridView_Liste_Ordres.GetFocusedRowCellValue("NO_ORDRE").ToString());
                    f_Fiche.Show();
                }
                catch (Exception excThrown)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(excThrown.Message);
                }
            }
```

Thank you in advance.

PS: the first constructor is just to create the NEW blank page, and the second constructor is to create NOT NEW (Edit page), so i passed the id and fill all control (textbox, memo, etc...)

Comment: What do you use OrderID for in the second constructor?

Comment: @dbaseman How this help you to resolve problem?

Comment: @Likurg well, given that's the only difference between the two constructors, I thought it might be pertinent, eh?

Comment: @dbaseman there is '....' in second constructor, i think there some implementation with using OrderID, however (IMHO) it does not  matter for current problem

Comment: by the way ...i modified le code, to show @Likurg what i use OrderID for.

Comment: So when you use Constructor without params eventhandler doesn't bind to EditValueChanged?

Comment: Is the value of `lookUpEdit_Dest` altered as a result of the extra code in the non default constructor? Without your implementation of the directly altered controls (textEdit_RefExpred, lookUpEdit_Agence, lookUpEdit_Transport) it is not possible to confirm or deny this. What additional code is in the second constructor?

Comment: Another thought - you have the stuff in the Construct_Page wrapped in a try statement - why? Perhaps this code is failing before you are adding the event handler is even added but you don't realise it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EditValueChanged` handles is wired in the very last line of `Constuct_Page`. Therefore it fires only for changes **after** `Constuct_Page`. Is it changed in the `..................` part of the code? It does sound like an over-simplified speculation, but it's worth double-checking anyway...

Besides, may I suggest you another improvement:

```
public Fiche_Ordre(string OrderID) : this.Fiche_Ordre()
{
  // invokes the other constructor first, so they're guaranteed
  // do be equivalent in the first part

  Pers_Ordre oPersOrdr = oOrder_BL.Get_OrdreOne_BL(ClientID,
    Convert.ToInt32(OrderID), false);

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put breakpoint and look on to lookUpEdit_Dest when you want bind eventhandler, i think that this var doesn't initialize, so you need to add initialize from second constructor to first.

Answer (score 0):

instead create Constuct_Page();  just put in Form_Load()